# How to disable Firebase when using Unity builds for window standalone build

Tags: windows, firebase, unity-game-engine

We have a mobile game for iOS and Android that works fine, one of our plugins is Firebase plugin (Analytics + Realtime database)

Now we want to export the game also to standalone mode (PC windows), and we want to disable the Firebase plugin completly when building to windows.

Of course we put #if everywhere needed, but still, the dlls are compiled into the project.

Is there an easy way to remove it during the standalone build?

Comment: Er, why don't you instruct your build system to do so. You *are* using a build system, right?

Comment: No, i'm using the standard Unity build